# penultimate date for each record

Tags: sql, date

I'm struggling with creation of select which shows me penultimate date for each record in my DB.

For example:

```
id  date
1   01.01.2018
1   05.01.2018
1   06.02.2018
2   01.06.2018
2   03.06.2018
3   12.12.2017
```

Out of this record I need to write `select`, which shows me following:

```
ID   max_date   penultimate
1   06.02.2018   05.01.2018
2   03.06.2018   01.06.2018
3   12.12.2017   NULL
```

Any idea how to do it? many thanks in advance

Comment: Which sql language are you using, and what version too

Comment: we are running MSSQL 2012, using t-sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `GROUP BY` to get the `MAX` and a correlated subquery with another `MAX` but this time lower than the former.

```
SELECT
    T.id,
    MAX(T.date) max_date,
    (
        SELECT
            MAX(N.date)
        FROM
            YourTable N
        WHERE
            N.id = T.id AND
            N.date < MAX(T.date)
    ) penultimate
FROM
    YourTable T
GROUP BY
    T.id
```

Answer (score 2):

Use conditional aggregation and the ANSI-standard `row_number()` or `dense_rank()` functions:

```
select id,
       max(date) as max_date,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then date end) as penultimate_date
from (select t.*,
             dense_rank() over (partition by id order by date desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum in (1, 2)
group by id;
```

Use `row_number()` if the dates can be the same in the event of ties.

Comment: This is a better answer than the correlated subquery answer imho, in terms of performance, flexibility, maintainability, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote in this way,

```
SELECT ID
    ,max(StartDate) MaxDate
    ,(
        SELECT StartDate
        FROM YourTable t2
        WHERE t2.id = t1.id
        ORDER BY StartDate DESC OFFSET 1 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROW ONLY
        ) penultimate
FROM YourTable t1
GROUP BY id
```

Answer (score 0):

Just an opitimized query:

```
;WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT id AS ID
        ,[date] AS max_date
        ,LEAD ([date], 1, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY [date] DESC) AS penultimate
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY [date] DESC) AS RN
    FROM Table3
)
SELECT ID,max_date,penultimate
FROM cte
WHERE RN=1
```

**[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/8662b/1)**