# I am trying to return a query that will give me the penultimate delivery_dates of for all users

Tags: sql, apache-spark, databricks

I am working with a databricks database and I have to write a query that will return the delivery_date of the penultimate order of all users (So the penultimate delivery_date). I have all of the historical delivery_date for all of the users but I am only interested in the penultimate delivery_date of all users.

I will try to walk you guys through what I am trying to accomplish using a simplified example.

When I run the code below for one user.

```
SELECT delivery_date_local
FROM order.orders 
WHERE lower(customer_login_visits) = '<my-email-here>@gmail.com'
```

I get the following results:

```
Delivery_date_local
2019-03-22
2019-03-22
2019-03-22
2019-03-22
2019-03-21
2019-03-20
```

What I want is the penultimate delivery_date_local for this user (and all other users) which in this case is 2019-03-22 but would be different if the user doesn't have more than one order on the same day.

This is the query I am running to get the desired results which is based on [a query I found on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51171800/penultimate-date-for-each-record).

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT(customer_login),
    MAX (delivery_date_local) as Last_order_date,
    MAX(case when seqnum = 2 then delivery_date_local end) as Penultimate_order_date
FROM (
    SELECT
        DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY customer_login_visits DESC) as seqnum
    FROM order.orders
)order.orders
WHERE seqnum IN (1,2)
GROUP BY customer_login_visits
```

But I am receiving the following error:

> Error in SQL statement: ParseException: 
>   mismatched input 'from' expecting (line 5, pos 0)

```
Select distinct  (customer_login),

           MAX(delivery_date_local) as Last_order_date,

           max(case when seqnum = 2 then

           delivery_date_local end) as Penultimate_order_date

from           (select 
^^^
```

I have read various post online and have tried different queries but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
SELECT o.*
FROM (SELECT o.*,
             DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY customer_login_visits ORDER BY Delivery_date_local
```

DESC) as seqnum
          FROM order.orders o
         ) o
    WHERE seqnum = 2;

This actually returns all orders on the penultimate date.  If you only want the date, then use `select distinct:

```
SELECT DISTINCT customer_login_visits, Delivery_date_local
FROM (SELECT o.*,
             DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY customer_login_visits ORDER BY Delivery_date_local DESC) as seqnum
      FROM order.orders o
     ) o
WHERE seqnum = 2;
```

Comment: Thanks a million @Gordon Linoff. It worked. The only thing I had to do was change the DENSE_RANK() to ROW_NUMBER for the reason given by wBob.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `DENSE_RANK` that will group those three distinct dates into three sequence numbers; 1, 2, 3.  If you want to get 22nd as an answer then try using `ROW_NUMBER` instead, eg something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM
  (
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY customer_login_visits ORDER BY delivery_date_local DESC ) AS seqnum, 
  customer_login_visits,
  delivery_date_local
  FROM order.orders
  )
WHERE seqnum = 2
```

Comment: Thanks a million for the advice about changing DENSE_RANK to ROW_RANK. You were right.

Comment: Would you consider marking this as the answer or do you need additional advice?